# Problem about the lever on a swing-top beer bottle. (Classical Mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

I'm faced with the following problem as stated in the image:

[image: This is the problem I'm referring to]

Once I find the geometry part, where I find what are the angles and the lengths and so on, to solve the forces I use 2 equations. The first ones is the equilibrium of forces in the y axis, and the second one is the equilibrium of momenta from the top point on the cork. Now the important thing I use which is the one I doubt is that I impose that the force on the bottom left point is $\textit{perpendicular}$ to the $L_1$ arm, and therefore parallel to the $L_2$ one. I had to do this since the equilibrium of momenta and forces in the 2 axis gives me 3 equations, and If I had left general horizontal and vertical forces in the two left points I'd have 4 unknowns, so in order to relate two of them I used that. I put down here what I did and what I obtained

[image]

Lastly, sorry about uploading it like this but this I wrote initially in a table, and thanks in advance for any insight about what I may have missed or do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Take the sum of the torques about point A , you obtain:

$$\vec \tau=\vec r_F\times \vec F+\vec r_H\times \vec F_H=\vec 0$$

with :

$$\vec r_F=\begin{bmatrix}
  \sqrt{L_1^2+L_2^2} \\
   0\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec F=F\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
   1\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\vec r_H=L_1\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\varphi)\\
   -\sin(\varphi)\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec F_H=F_H\begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
   1\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and
$$\varphi=\arctan\left(\frac {L_2}{L_1}\right)$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec \tau=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ 
\sqrt {{L_{{1}}}^{2}+{L_{{2}}}^{2}}F+L_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi 
 \right) F_{{H}}\end {array} \right] 
=\vec 0$$

$$|F_H|=F\,\frac{\sqrt{L_1^2+L_2^2}}{L_1\,\cos(\varphi)}$$

thus :

$$F_1=|F_H|\,\cos(\psi)$$

with
$$\tan(\psi)=\frac {x}{y}=\frac{L_1\,\cos(\varphi)}{L_3-L_1\,\sin(\varphi)}$$

Comment: Okey thanks a lot, but i do have one question. If you take the limit $L_1=L_2 \rightarrow 0$, you get $\varphi \approx \pi/4$, $\psi \approx 0$, then $F_H \approx 2F$ and $F_1 \approx 2F$. And I get mindboggled by that, I would expect that if you have basically only a vertical arm and a downward force F, you'd just get F, not $2F$. Is there something I'm not taking into account?

Comment: $\psi$ is not zero $\psi(\varphi=\pi/4)=\frac 12\,{\frac {L_{{1}}\sqrt {2}}{L_{{3}}-\frac 12\,L_{{1}}\sqrt {2}}}$

Comment: If $L_1$ tends to zero it does, but I guess the $2F$ thing it's just something I have to wrap my head around. Thanks a lot for the answer!